# How can I join 2 different counts of the same table together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The table I'm working on is records of answers to certain amount of questions. I want to find out the percentage of people said 'Yes, definitely' about provider 23 in question 470,477,479,481,483. So I tried to count the total number of answers and the 'Yes, definitely' answers. I can do them separately but fail to join them in one table.

One query is to get the total counts of the records in table SurveyAnswerFact.

```
SELECT SurveyQuestionKey, count(1)
FROM [WAREHOUSE].[dbo].[SurveyAnswerFact]
WHERE ([ProviderKey] = 23) 
AND ([SurveyQuestionKey] IN (470,477,479,481,483))        
AND ([Response] = 'Yes, definitely') 
AND ([ResponseDateKey] BETWEEN 20140601 AND 20150531)
GROUP BY SurveyQuestionKey
```

Results:

```
470   44
477   40
479   43
481   43
483   44
```

Another query is to get the counts of the answers that are 'Yes, definitely'

```
SELECT SurveyQuestionKey, count(1)
FROM [WAREHOUSE].[dbo].[SurveyAnswerFact]
WHERE (ProviderKey = 23) 
AND (SurveyQuestionKey IN (470,477,479,481,483)) 
AND ([ResponseDateKey] BETWEEN 20140601 AND 20150531)
GROUP BY SurveyQuestionKey
```

Results:

```
470   43
477   39
479   35
481   42
483   39
```

I tried to join them together using SQL, but the results are same as the first query's results. My expected result is like this:

```
470   43   44
477   39   40
479   35   43
481   42   43
483   39   44
```

Can anybody teach me the correct way to join them?

Comment: What's the question?  Two different counts of what?  Provide some sample data and expected results...

Comment: I just edited the question. I was testing if the code block works :). First question at stack overflow. Thanks.

Comment: edited question much easier to understand :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean...

all I did was eliminate where clause on the response and added it to the select and group by.

```
 SELECT SurveyQuestionKey, Response, count(1)
    FROM [WAREHOUSE].[dbo].[SurveyAnswerFact]
    WHERE ([ProviderKey] = 23) 
      AND ([SurveyQuestionKey] IN (470,477,479,481,483))        
      AND ([ResponseDateKey] BETWEEN 20140601 AND 20150531)
   GROUP BY SurveyQuestionKey, Response
```

--------------UPDATE BASED ON NEW INFO---------

There's a few ways to do this.  use a case statement

```
SELECT SurveyQuestionKey, count(1) as Totalcount, sum(case when Response = 'Yes, definitely' then 1 else 0 end) as [Yes Def]
FROM [WAREHOUSE].[dbo].[SurveyAnswerFact]
WHERE ([ProviderKey] = 23) 
AND ([SurveyQuestionKey] IN (470,477,479,481,483))        
AND ([ResponseDateKey] BETWEEN 20140601 AND 20150531)
GROUP BY SurveyQuestionKey
```

Another way would be to join the tables as you suggest but this has more overhead. (this uses a common table for each query to make the join easier to read.)

```
With totalCount as (SELECT SurveyQuestionKey, count(1) cnt
FROM [WAREHOUSE].[dbo].[SurveyAnswerFact]
WHERE ([ProviderKey] = 23) 
AND ([SurveyQuestionKey] IN (470,477,479,481,483))        
AND ([Response] = 'Yes, definitely') 
AND ([ResponseDateKey] BETWEEN 20140601 AND 20150531)
GROUP BY SurveyQuestionKey),

YesDefCount as (SELECT SurveyQuestionKey, count(1) cnt
FROM [WAREHOUSE].[dbo].[SurveyAnswerFact]
WHERE ([ProviderKey] = 23) 
AND ([SurveyQuestionKey] IN (470,477,479,481,483))        
AND ([ResponseDateKey] BETWEEN 20140601 AND 20150531)
GROUP BY SurveyQuestionKey)

SELECT surveyQuestionKey, totalcount.cnt, yesDefCount.count
from totalcount A
LEFT JOIN YESDEFCOUNT B 
 on A.SurveyQuestionKey = B.SurveyQuestionKey;
```

Comment: Hi, I just edited the question. Could you please take a look at it again? thank you!

Comment: I got a "Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'sum' is not a recognized built-in function name." error on the first one... I googled it, but I don't understand...could you help again?

Comment: OH my god I add a ')' after 'end'. It works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: yeah I forgot a closing )... Another way to do this would be with pivot tables, but I thought that would be overkill for now

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SurveyQuestionKey, count(1), x.totals
  FROM [WAREHOUSE].[dbo].[SurveyAnswerFact], 
       (select count(1) totals from [WAREHOUSE].[dbo].[SurveyAnswerFact]) x
 WHERE ([ProviderKey] = 23) 
   AND ([SurveyQuestionKey] IN (470,477,479,481,483))        
   AND ([Response] = 'Yes, definitely') 
   AND ([ResponseDateKey] BETWEEN 20140601 AND 20150531)
 GROUP BY SurveyQuestionKey
```

Comment: You got my idea before I edited it! But it notified that "Column 'x.totals' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." Can you help me correct it?